Is it obvious that Global Choice holds for $\mathrm{ZF}^-$?
As $\mathrm{ZF}^-$ ($\mathrm{ZF}$ minus the power set axiom) only has countable sets, does it not mean that Global Choice holds for $\mathrm{ZF}^-$ because $\mathrm{V}$ can be bijected with $\mathrm{Ord}$, or, for that matter, with $\mathbb{N}$?

$\mathsf{ZF}^-$ makes no commitment as to whether there are uncountable sets. Maybe you're looking at $\mathsf{ZF}^-$ + "All sets are countable"?

The statement "$\mathsf{ZF}^-$ has only countable sets" is false. $\mathsf{ZF}^-$ makes no commitment to the existence or not of uncountable sets. I suspect the theory you actually have in mind is $\mathsf{ZF}^-$ + "All sets are countable." So modified, the answer to your question is negative: just because each set is countable does not mean that the universe as a whole is countable, and indeed it's easy to produce models of $\mathsf{ZF}^-$ + "Every set is countable" in which global choice fails.
Here's one way to do that. Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a model of $\mathsf{ZF}$ + "The reals are not well-orderable," and let $\mathcal{X}=H_{\omega_1}^\mathcal{M}$ be the hereditarily countable sets in $\mathcal{M}$. It's easy to check that $\mathcal{X}\models\mathsf{ZF}^-$ + "Every set is countable." However, since $\mathbb{R}^\mathcal{M}\subseteq\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{M}$ has no well-ordering of $\mathbb{R}^\mathcal{M}$, global choice fails in $\mathcal{X}$ (more precisely: $\mathcal{X}$ does not admit a definable well-ordering).

Thanks! Is $\mathrm{ZF}^-$ + $\mathrm{V}=\mathrm{L}$ perhaps the most reasonable way to obtain global choice?

@FrodeAlfsonBjørdal What's reasonable or not depends entirely on what your goals and criteria for success are.

Of course. More precisely, will Global Choice hold for $\mathrm{ZF}^-$ + $\mathrm{V}=\mathrm{L}$?

@FrodeAlfsonBjørdal Yes, via the usual L-ordering. Powerset isn't needed there.
